# Conditional independence and factorization

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Does $a \perp\hspace{-1.3ex}\perp b \mid d$ imply $p(a,b,c\mid d) = p(a,c\mid d)\ p(b,c\mid d)$?

Comment: No. Try $c=a$ (or a host of other counterexamples).

Comment: I don't see this yet. I think I don't know exactly how the joint probability is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Assume for example that $c=a$, then for every $(x,y,z)$, 
$$
P[a=x,b=y,c=x\mid d=z]=P[a=x,b=y\mid d=z],
$$ 
while 
$$
P[a=x,c=x\mid d=z]\cdot P[b=y,c=x\mid d=z]=P[a=x\mid d=z]\cdot P[a=x,b=y\mid d=z],
$$ 
hence, in general, the LHS is greater than the RHS.